# Is the following std::vector code valid?

Tags: c++, stdvector

```
std::vector<Foo> vec;
Foo foo(...);

assert(vec.size() == 0);
vec.reserve(100); // I've reserved 100 elems
vec[50] = foo; // but I haven't initialized any of them
// so am I assigning into uninitialized memory?
```

Is the above code safe?

Comment: Generally speaking, I tend to prefer `at` to `operator[]`. Although semantically identical and a bit longer to write, it does have the so-called `bound-checking` feature. I would never consider anything that write outside the boundaries as `safe`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not valid. The vector has no elements, so you cannot access any element of them. You just reserved space for `100` elements (which means that it's guaranteed that no reallocation happens until over 100 elements have been inserted).

The fact is that you cannot resize the vector without also initializing the elements (even if just default initializing).

Answer (score 4):

You should use `vec.resize(100)` if you want to index-in right away.

`vec[50]` is only safe if `50 < vec.size()`. `reserve()` doesn't change the size of a vector, but `resize()` does *and* constructs the contained type.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. While the container has 100 elements reserved, it still has 0 elements.

You need to insert elements in order to access that portion of memory. Like Jon-Eric said, `resize()` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector::reserve(100) will claim 100*sizeof(Foo) of free memory, so that further insertion to a vector will not do a memory allocation until 100*sizeof(foo) is full, but accessing the element of that vector will give indeterministic content of that element, since its only claim the memory not allocate it.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use operator[] to access 50th element you should either call resize, push_back() something 50 times or use std::fill_n algorithm.

Comment: `std::uninitialized_fill_n` is no better than what he's doing.

Comment: You're right, fill_n() requires elements of vector to be intialized. But I guess std::generate() can be used instead.

Comment: No, `generate` with a simple function is no different from `fill_n` which isn't as close to what we want as `uninitialized_fill_n`. No generic algorithm will work here because STL algos change sequences, not containers. A `back_insert_iterator` would be a roundabout way of doing this, if you are set on using `<algorithm>`.

Comment: And again you're right. I guess I should be paying more attention to documentation and use stl more :)