# STL sort algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl, vector

I'm trying to sort an array of numbers in ascending order and don't know whats wrong with my code (I'm completely new to vectors). I should first copy the input array (data) into an STL vector, then apply STL’s sorting algorithm to the vector, and finally copy the vector back into the array.

```
void STLSort(int data[],int size)
{
vector<int> a1;
a1.reserve(size);
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    a1[i]=data[i];
sort(a1.begin(),a1.end());
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    data[i]=a1[i];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4765910/51831

Comment: ... and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2384137/51831

Comment: You don't need that mess, one of the advantages of the STL algorithms is that you can apply them also to regular arrays, since pointers can act as iterators without any problem...

Comment: Alternately, instead of messing around with arrays in the first place, just use the vector and pass it around as needed. You will save yourself many more headaches.

Answer (score 4):

You can sort the range directly:

```
void sort_me(int * arr, unsigned int size)
{
  std::sort(arr, arr + size);
}

int main()
{
  int a[] = { 3, 11, 7 };
  sort_me(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));

  // or even just in-place:
  int b[] = { 12, -1, 88, 0 };
  std::sort(b, b + sizeof(b)/sizeof(int));
}
```

Even more hip: a template:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N>
void sort_me_v2(T (&arr)[N])
{
  std::sort(arr, arr + N);
}

int main()
{
  int c[] = { -1, 2, -3, 4 };
  sort_me_v2(c);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a1.reserve(size);
```

This allocates place for the items, but does not change the `size()` of the vector. In effect, `end()` is the same as `begin()` so you're sorting an empty `vector`. You should use

```
a1.resize(size);
```

Comment: In fact he won't reach the `sort` anyway, if he's lucky.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Why wouldn't he? `operator[]` isn't required to do bounds checking.

Comment: Oh, I guess you're right. Though it's UB, the memory is actually there so it should work in practice. I forgot the `reserve`.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Definitely UB and *some* (eg. debug) library might catch it. But a straightforward implementation probably wouldn't.